# Difference between inheriting IDispatch and declaring interface type

Tags: c#

What is the difference between inheriting IDispatch directly (IMyInterface: IDispatch) and declaring interface type [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)] ?

Comment: Why would you want to 1) declare IDispatch and 2) derive from it, while the framework can do the work for you?

Comment: A big difference is that you'll need to implement IDispatch yourself if you don't use the attribute.  Which is *not* simple.  There's no point in doing this.

Comment: Thanks guys for clarifying. I bumped into a code with both of those approaches and did't really understand.